# Understanding ie8fix & es5-shim

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, es5-shim

I'm having a hard time trying to understand  what exactly es5-shim and ie8fix do.
Can anyone explain them in simple language please?
(Do not only quote from wikipedia and other sources!!)

Comment: What research have you done, and what parts (with complicated language?) did you not understand?

Comment: @Bergi I think the question is pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

[ES5 mostly introduced new functionality rather than new syntax/features.](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch25.html) This means that most ES5 code is valid syntax for ES3. For example, `Array.prototype.map` simply adds a new function to Array.prototype, which you could do yourself [in ES3](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim/blob/bc7f92822b9019c4906d6fb8983b3adf9c3a5a21/es5-shim.js#L476):

```
Array.prototype.map = function ( callback, thisArg ) {

    var newArr = [];

    for ( var i = 0; i < this.length; i ++ )
        newArr.push( callback.call( thisArg || window, this[ i ], i, this ) );

    return newArr;

};
```

ES5-shim simply does this for as many ES5 functions as it possibly can; where it cannot, it tries to silently fail instead of halting code execution (such as with `Object.seal`). It doesn't provide any backwards support for new syntax (which is limited) or features, as that's not really possible in the general sense (you could theoretically do some it by building your own interpreter and hijacking scripts/eval).

I'm unsure what ie8fix is, but it might be similar to es5-shim except specifically for IE8 where es5-shim does not cover.